# unable to link noip ddns to my kali linux

Tags: linux, domain-name-system, debian, port-forwarding, ddns

1. I registered a domain bookmarks.ddns.net in noip.com website and added to my router => Dynamic DNS Configuration settings
2. Downloaded and installed noip script on kali linux and its changing dynamic ip to noip website that means working fine
3. Here are my iptables:

   ```
   # iptables -S
   -P INPUT ACCEPT
   -P FORWARD ACCEPT
   -P OUTPUT DROP
   -A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT        
   -A OUTPUT -d 192.168.0.0/16 -j ACCEPT
   -A OUTPUT -d 10.0.0.0/8 -j ACCEPT
   -A OUTPUT -d 172.16.0.0/12 -j ACCEPT
   -A OUTPUT -o tun+ -j ACCEPT
   -A OUTPUT -d 127.0.0.1/32 -j ACCEPT
   -A OUTPUT -d 185.217.68.195/32 -j ACCEPT
   ```
4. Made sure port 80 is opened locally

   ```
   nmap 192.168.1.3 -p 80
   Starting Nmap 7.70 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2018-05-26 19:00 +0430
   Nmap scan report for 192.168.1.3
   Host is up (0.000085s latency).

   PORT   STATE SERVICE
   80/tcp open  http

   Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 2.81 seconds
   ```
5. when I try to access in browser http://bookmarks.ddns.net/ then its now working and

   ```
   This site can’t be reached
   http://bookmarks.ddns.net/ is unreachable.
   Go to http://ddns.net/
   Search Google for bookmarks ddns net
   ERR_ADDRESS_UNREACHABLE
   ```

I am running windscribe VPN service. Please advise where I am making mistake?

Best regards

Comment: VPNs are generally used for outgoing access.  It does not appear you are allowing incoming traffic on your router

Comment: @BillThor how can I allow incoming traffic on my router?

Comment: It depends on what router you have.  Login to the router, and check the options it provides.  There should be a panel for adding port forwarding.   Forward port 80 to your server.